# How to get Index Row number from Source Model

Tags: python, qt, model, pyqt, qtableview

Clicking the `QTableView` "**Item_B_001**" prints out its row number # **0**.

But in source model's `self.items` this item corresponds to the number # 3.  How to get a "real" Source Model's Item's row number - a number it really corresponds to?

[image]

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import sys

class Model(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, *args):
        QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent, *args)
        self.items = ['Item_A_001','Item_A_002','Item_B_001','Item_B_002']

    def rowCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.items)       
    def columnCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return 1

    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid(): return QVariant()
        elif role != Qt.DisplayRole:
            return QVariant()

        row=index.row()
        if row<len(self.items):
            return QVariant(self.items[row])
        else:
            return QVariant()

class Proxy(QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Proxy, self).__init__()

    def filterAcceptsRow(self, row, parent):
        if '_B_' in self.sourceModel().data(self.sourceModel().index(row, 0), Qt.DisplayRole).toPyObject():
            return True
        return False

class MyWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args)

        tableModel=Model(self)               

        proxyModel=Proxy()
        proxyModel.setSourceModel(tableModel)

        self.tableview=QTableView(self) 
        self.tableview.setModel(proxyModel)
        self.tableview.clicked.connect(self.viewClicked)
        self.tableview.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.tableview)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def viewClicked(self, indexClicked):
        print 'index of proxy row', indexClicked.row()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you could use the `QAbstractProxyModel::mapToSource()` function to return the model index in the source model that corresponds to the index in the proxy model. I.e. (not sure about Python syntax):

```
def viewClicked(self, indexClicked):
    print 'index of proxy row', self.proxyModel.mapToSource(indexClicked).row()
```